# Unable to access site after force https and ssl

Tags: ssl, https

Yesterday I made a mistake: enabled force HTTPS and force SSL. And shortly I understood my mistake.

I was able to connect to host and change force_ssl from '2' to '0'. But site is still unaccessable.

**htaccess.txt** :

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 13415 2009-11-03 15:53:25Z ian $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2008 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

How can I disable force HTTPS? Which file I need to change?

Comment: What does your .htaccess file look like?

Comment: Thise derives from the `configuration.php` file. Merry christmas btw

Comment: Merry Christmas. I have updated my question with content of htaccess. Hope it can help

Comment: Do you get any error, or just a blank screen? Also confirming that you have a valid SSL certificate installed?

Comment: I don't have valid ssl certificate installed. This is why I am trying to revert changes (force HTTPS and force SSL), so that site would be accessible again.

Comment: In the database, go to the #__extensions table and see if you have a plugin forcing the SSL

Comment: Since we are now in the era of free ssl certificates, I feel the best solution is to get everything working **with** https.  Conflict resolution rather than conflict avoidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank all of you for help.

Problem why changing 2 to 0 in force_ssl did not helped was Chrome cache. Appearently Chrome saved that this site is https and do not allowed to go to http. Crearing cache solved the issue.

Although I still want to get site working on HTTPS. But this will be separate case.